# Connect ESP32 cam to the Nodemcu motor shield

Tags: esp8266, esp32, nodemcu, camera

Is it possible to connect ESP32 cam to the Nodemcu motor shield? I already have a ESP8266 chip connected to the Nodemcu motor shield.

In get this error after connecting this ESP32 cam to the Nodemcu motor shield like this

```
VCC: Connect to 5V on the NodeMCU motor shield
GND: Connect to GND on the NodeMCU motor shield
UnR: Connect to TX on the NodeMCU motor shield
U0T: Connect to RX on the NodeMCU motor shield
```

***A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header***